# Integrate angular js directive inside angular 7 component

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-directive, angular2-directives, angular7

Is it possible to integrate Angular js directive inside Angular 7 component at the runtime. The Angular js is a separate project module with its own folder stucture.This folder structure includes directives as well. Can these angular js directives be imported into Angular 7 application by providing the directive's file path and used in Angular 7 component template. Kindly suggest if there is a way to do this.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT recommended. The architectures and life cycles of both are very different and *you are just increasing the chances of errors, time and effort by doing so*.

To answer your question: Yes, there is a way to do it as you can manipulate the DOM using any JS lib/framework and by using your ng7's @ViewChild/templateRefs to gain control of the element, but you will face issues while updating data to/from Angular7.

I'd highly suggest you make a new ng2+ component and import the code from your old project and work on it to make it into an Angular2+ component.